# Php login system for different users

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to Php programming and I'm having some troubles understanding it. I need to make a project that will manage students and their grades. I need to have 2 types of users, professors and students. A professor can add grades to students, and a student can only view his grades.

I managed to make a simple login system, using wampserver and phpmyadmin.
Now I don't know how to represent the students and the professors (since the teachers can add grades I assume they are treated like some sort of admins and students are users).Should I put a checkbox on the login page? And after that I should create different pages to each type of user?

Do not get confused by my questions. I don't need any code just some ideas on how to get started. After that if I have any problems I will share my code also.

Comment: What would the checkbox on the login page be used for? You could treat everyone as a user, but then include a usergroup value of 1 and 0 (1 for admin, 0 for users), and then use PHP if statements to show or hide admin controls based on this value for each user logged in.

Comment: much, much too broad

Comment: Manage your registered users with `role` like `professor`, `sutdent` and divide functionality and permissions according to role.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all quite basic.

Assuming you have saved the users in your database, you simply have to add a column to the table those users are saved in. You could call this column 'flags'. If the user is a student, you could give it the value 1. If the user is a professor however you would give it a value 2.

In your code when you verify the login, i reckon you put their data in a SESSION. So now, with the new column present. Place that value in your SESSION as well.

Now that we can distinguish user and professor, we could simply do:

```
if ($_SESSION['flags'] == 2) {
    // Something only the professor can do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same table for all users you can add one more column in your table with name 'is_teacher'. which could be 1 or 0.
In this way you can differentiate if the user is a teacher or student

Answer (score 1):

Since you want some kind of admin system, make a row in your database table with an integer in it, In Example: student1 has INT 0, 0 will be student, teacher1 has INT 1, 1 will be teacher.

Then when you log in get this INT and paste it in a session, then let that session decide if the student or teacher page is loaded.

Thats what i would do at least :).

Answer (score 0):

add one column type take enum(1,0); 1 for teacher and 0 for studant so that you can send type when adding user which you want and show the functionality as on its type.